# Как закрыть Player Settings Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Знаю,очень глупый вопрос , но вот такая проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачал unity hub и обновил проект , после пару часов случайно открыл окно на весь экран.

Фишка в том что при выходе размер и само окно сохраняется.

Вопрос:как закрыть его?

Горячие клавиши ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема крылась в моей панели инструментов - она была не как у всех снизу , а сверху и для того что бы увидеть "верхнюю часть" unity (тогда вы сможете закрыть player settings) вам нужно включить "автоматически скрывать панель задач".

Answer (score -1):

Как это вообще получилось? Окно сцены защищает от полного перекрывания себя, да и вообще все окна не дадут сделать себя слишком маленькими. Не представляю, как так получилось. Можешь попробовать переустановить Unity, может поможет

Comment: К сожалению, переустанавливать unity я не очень хочу , но проблему мне нужно решить.Думаю это проблемы unity hub .

Comment: За что минус? Чем не понравилось?

Comment: Ответ помог ,но косвенно.                                         
                             PS:Минус не мой